# Open-source software for designing augmented reality Android apps in Linux Mint

Tags: android, linux, software-development

I want to develop an Android app for augmented reality. I tried ARToolKit, ARCore, Unity(3d), and Vuforia. But all these provide better support for Windows than for Linux Mint.

I am using Linux Mint 18. I am feeling difficulty in using them for developing an Android app as well, as for getting tutorials related to them (for Linux Mint).

I want an Linux Mint compatible open-source software for developing an augmented reality Android app. It would be helpful, if tutorials are present for that.

Comment: Running a Beta For Linux of Unity3d on my Mint workstations, crashed occasionally so just save and back up often.  Works fine otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

OK, since the question got moved here, I'll turn my comment into an answer.

I'm 100% linux desktop - Mint 19 now - at home, work, on my laptop, and in my classroom.

Android Studio tends to Just Work.

First, install Java using the webupd8 team PPA - https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java

First -  some prerequisites.  Make sure your system is up to date

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then install some supporting libraries

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
```

Then install KVM (if your CPU supports it, if you are using virtualbox to run the Linux system then skip this step)

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder bridge-utils ia32-libs-multiarch virt-manager
```

Now time for Android Studio.

Add a ppa

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:maarten-fonville/android-studio
```

Then update your software lists

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then install  Android Studio with

```
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

This will download a BIG 470mb file and install it.

Then edit the `/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh` file.  At the top of it, before `message(){`  add a line so it looks like:

```
export LD_PRELOAD='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6'
message(){
```

You should have a entry on your menu for Android Studio.  Launch it, and it will ask you to configure and set it up.  Choose the custom setup, pick the theme you like and be sure to install the Android Emulator.  More downloading - another 1.5gb or so. But when it is done, you should be ready to go.

Unity3d also runs natively in linux, at least the beta version from late 2017 does.  Checking the release page, they've been busy, and there are very recent releases available.  Anyway, only issues with it on my system are a tendency to crash on start up.  Save early, save often, backup often.  Stuff I tend to do anyway.  No trick to installing, assuming above for Android has already been done (I've not tested a Unity install on a freshly installed system)